# In AS3, when a streamed video freezes, how can you detect that?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, streaming, flash-media-server

What is a good, reliable way to detect if a video over a NetStream freezes mid-stream?  I need to know this for RTMP and RTMFP, although my guess is that the protocol doesn't really matter here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely have to run the debugger or set up a timer to poll this but take a look at

netstream.info

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#info

Comment: I tried using that after you mentioned it, but I haven't a reliable way to use that yet.  At first it looked like videoBytesPerSecond and audioBytesPerSecond could be relied upon, but apparently they can sometimes act perfectly normal after someone stops actually transmitting any new video or audio (apparently Firefox just keeps transmitting blank stuff anyway).

Comment: can you validate this by seeing if the value stays the same, then you know it's frozen?  Also, what about other browsers?

Comment: IE and Chrome act normal about it - you pull the camera out of the USB port, they stop pushing video through.  But I would do that while running Firefox, and it would still be trying to push some sort of dummy video through (though the image on the other side would be completely still).  The videoBytesPerSecond count was pretty heavily reduced in that case, but it would still grow, decline, and stay around 30-42KBps where I had set the Camera object's bandwidth property to 64KBps.